# Getting error while using "predict" method for Markov chain implemenattion in R using clickstream package

Tags: r, statistics

I have data set for user wise, clicks pattern for each session for one online site.I would like to predict next clicks using Markov chain & its probability.

```
Following is the my Code:

library(clickstream);
cls2<-readClickstreams(file.choose(),sep = ',',header = TRUE);
mc2<-fitMarkovChain(clickstreamList = cls2,order = 2,control = list(optimizer= "linear"));
pattern <- new("Pattern", sequence = c("/clsisGre/PersonalDetailForm.jsp","/clsisGre/PersonalDetail.jsp"),                                         absorbingProbabilities = data.frame(NULL = 0.9, Success = 0.1));
> resultPattern <- predict(mc2, startPattern = pattern, dist = 1);

Error Message is :

Error in if (nextState %in% object@absorbingStates) { : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In max(cp, na.rm = T) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Need help to handle this error/exception.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late update but I am able to crack this problem, So I m posting the same solution which might be helpful for others.
In code (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,l,m) is the sequence input for which I would like to build Markov chain.Below code will help to handle the error mentioned in above post.

```
  pattern <- new("Pattern", sequence = c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,l,m),
                   absorbingProbabilities = data.frame(NULL = 0.9, Success = 0.1));
    possibleError <- tryCatch(
      suppressWarnings( predict(mc2, startPattern = pattern, dist = 1)),
      error=function(e) e
    );

    if(inherits(possibleError, "error")) next
    resultPattern <- predict(mc2, startPattern = pattern, dist = 1);

    aa<-attributes(resultPattern)$absorbingProbabilities;
    success_mat10[i,2]<-aa$Success;
    success_mat10[i,1]<-as.vector(url_mat10[i,1]);
```